# "Election ends: tomorrow" is too imprecise

Tags: feature-request, election, date-format

[Example](//codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1):

> #### nomination period began
>
> Jun 29 at 20:00
>
> #### primary voting begin
>
> Jul 6 at 20:00
>
> #### election began
>
> 2 days ago
>
> #### election ends
>
> tomorrow

I'm not particularly concerned about the exact time when each of the phases began, but I think that the exact deadline for voting is important information.  What exactly does "tomorrow" mean?  That could be anywhere from 1 minute to 47 hours in the future.

Could you make it more explicit?

Comment: Since it is now at "23 hours", it seems that "tomorrow" means greater than 24 hours.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can hover over nearly any timestamp on SE to get the exact value. That works here too.

Comment: Never seen (and thought too) so many self-answers from the OP itself.

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by @Catija's comment:

> #### election ends
>
> Jul 14 at 20:00 (25 hours from now)

… and the countdown would update dynamically, similar to the way the "answered 20 mins ago" timestamps work on questions and answers.  The human-friendly units should switch from days to hours at 48 hours.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution: just use the same date-time format everywhere.

> #### election began
>
> Jul 11 at 20:00
>
> #### election ends
>
> Jul 14 at 20:00

Answer (score 2):

Suggested wording, if you want any human-friendly display at all:

> #### election began
>
> 2 days ago
>
> #### election ends
>
> Jul 14 at 20:00 (tomorrow)

Answer (score 1):

On further investigation, there is a tooltip that appears when hovering.  And the text changes from "tomorrow" to "in 23 hours".

The UI isn't very obvious, but maybe keeping the status quo is not so bad after all.

Answer (score 1):

A countdown clock would be nice.

I am suggesting that it either be replaced with a count down clock (*Happy <strike>New Year</strike> Graduation*) or that a count down clock be an addition to some of the other suggestions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: how is this not an answer to the question but the other suggestions are?  where is the line that I am not seeing?

Comment: @Malachi: I have no idea, but three people thought so. Very strange.